# Liquid galium speed of sound

Tags: acoustics, metals

What is speed of sound in liquid galium? I see water have speed 1400 m/s,and ice 4000 m/s so the change is very big in solid/liquid phase change,I assume same is true for pure metal like galium.There is list in wikipedia that shows speed of sound in elemements and galium is shown to have 2740 m/s,but I am not sure if that is solid or liquid state.

Comment: The speed of sound in liquid metals can be generalized - for any metal but you have to assume a pressure and a temperature as well as metal density. The speed of sound is generally different for liquid/solid states.

Comment: Density 6 g/cm3.... pressure 1 atmosphere ... temperature 30 celsius.Are you sure about the generalization? I ask becose galium is very different to most other metals,while they melt on average at 1000 celsius,Galium melts at 29 celsius,I am no expert,but I have feeling that the extremly low melting temperature can cause problems for generalizations.